# ngfor use index in elements click event

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to make a remove button on my chips so I tried:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let condition of conditions; let i = index">
    {{condition.column.friendlyName}} {{condition.operator.symbol}} {{condition.value}} 
    <mat-icon class="close-icon" (click)="removeChip(i)">highlight_off</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

but it says `i` is not defined.  What is correct way to get the chips index when it is clicked?

Comment: The error message is displayed at run time, at compile time, or in the code editor? Your code should work, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ojsjo-9mspzb).

Comment: You  can this multiple ways. You can use the index (which is what you are trying to do) or you can pass the the object like this `removeChip(condition)` then use `indexOf` to find the position(index) in the array then remove it with `slice()`  ;). if you post a stackbliz we can problably help you better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is updated in angular 5+ to `index as i`:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let condition of conditions; index as i"> 
  {{condition.column.friendlyName}} {{condition.operator.symbol}} {{condition.value}} 
  <mat-icon class="close-icon" (click)="removeChip(i)">highlight_off</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

Comment: `let i = index` in angular 5+ is still valid. `index as i`  is not creating a new variables. All is doing is a keyword and this was introduced in Angular 4 if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: `let i = index` didn't work but when i changed it to `index as i` it worked.